# Supremum/Infimum of a Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let a function $f:[-3,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            2|x|+1 & \quad x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
            0 & \quad x \notin \mathbb{Q}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Let $P = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, ..., x_{n}\}$ be any partition of $[-3,3]$.

Then, since each subinterval $[x_{k-1}, x_{k}]$ contains both rational and irrational numbers,

$sup \{f(x) | x \in [x_{k-1}, x_{k}]=1$

and

$inf \{f(x) | x \in [x_{k-1}, x_{k}]=0$.

Am I interpreting the supremum and infimum correctly?

Comment: Why do you say that the $\sup$ is equal to $1$? It depends on the way $f$ is defined.

Comment: My thinking is that over an arbitrary interval the least upper bound would be 1 since if x is rational, the function value will be at least 1. I am having a hard time thinking of the supremum with this function.

Comment: Your supremum definition is wrong

Comment: Take the interval $I=[0,1/10]$. What are the values of $f$ if $x \in I$ is irrational? If $x \in I$ is rational? The best is to start taking some examples like $1/10$ or $\pi/100$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  Regardless of which interval $I=[x_{k-1}, x_{k}]$ that I choose, isn't the least upper bound $2|x_{k}|+1$? Or I am attributing the supremum to the max?

Comment: You’re almost there. The issue is for intervals such that $0 \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$. In that case it is a bit more complex. Look also carefully at the case $x_{k-1} < x_k <0$. Also, have you drawn a sketch of $f$ graph? It will help you to understand what happens.

Comment: Suppose $|x_k|\ge |x_{k-1}|$. Note that $2|x_k|-1$ is the supremum,  not necessarily the maximum. They are the same only if $x_k\in \mathbb Q$. For example the interval $[0,1/\sqrt 2]$ does not have a maximum

Comment: @Andrei Why $2|x_{k}|-1$?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. It is $2|x_k|+1$

Comment: Whew, I thought I was missing the a fundamental understanding of supremum.

Comment: Can I conclude that because over any arbitrary interval the lower sum is not equal to the upper sum, that f is not Riemann integrable?  Meaning, to prove this function is not Riemann integrable, don't I need to show that for ANY partition, the lower and upper integrals are not equal?

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to prove that $f$ is not Riemann integrable, then it is simpler.

For any partition $P \equiv -3 =x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n=3$ of $[-3,3]$, you have $L(f,P)=0$ as $\inf\limits_{x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]} f(x)=0$ for $0 \le i <n$. Therefore if $f $ was Riemann integrable on $[-3,3]$ it’s integral $s$ would be equal to $0$.

However for $x \in [2,3] \cap \mathbb Q$ when have $f(x) \ge 2\vert 2 \vert +1 =5$. Hence $$\sup\limits_{x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]} f(x)\ge 5$$ for all the integers $0 \le i <n$ for which $[x_i,x_{i+1}] \cap [2,3] \neq \emptyset$.

This implies $U(f,P) \ge 5*(3-2)=5$, proving that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thank you for this...my main goal is to understand what is happening all together at a deeper level, so I wanted to address "any" partition and be able to see it and explain it. This makes perfect sense though.